# Formal "The works were performed in full" in German

Tags: formality

When drawing up documents it is necessary sometimes to state that

> The works were performed in full.

I would translate it in the following way

> Die Leistungen (for example: *unter Geltung des Vertrages*) sind vollständig erbracht.

Is there a more formal way to say the same?

Comment: A few notes. There is no "more formal", just "formal" or "not formal". And that sentence *is* formal. Replace "sind" with "wurden", though.

Comment: @Em1 Thanks for the info! Renaming my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so... It's already very formal. I'd add a *worden* if it's meant to go into a juristic/technical direction, to make clear this desired part of the contract was fulfilled, but actually leaving *worden* out already makes it as formal as I think it can get.

> Die Leistungen sind .. erbracht worden.
>   Die Leistungen wurden erbracht.

The way you put it first is grammatically correct. It is a form that sounds slightly poetic and aloof, having been used in historic dramatic poems or such.

> Die Leistungen sind erbracht.

It's a bit like saying "It was I" instead of "It was me."